# React-query Global enabled/disabled hooks

Tags: react-native, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am working on a react native app using react-query. We have 11 query hooks that retrieve information from our server. 3 of those hooks can run without auth tokens, but the rest needs an auth token. Currently each hook has different ways to be enabled: !!authToken or a different condition. No problem with this.

However when a user signs out our logs indicates that all queries are being triggered, We are using the below code into a signout hook.

queryClient.clear()
queryClient.removeQueries()

Also is it a good practice to create a new queryClient when a new token is generated, that way we can enable most of the queries from global config?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`.clear` and `.removeQueries` are both ways of clearing the cache.  Clearing the cache causes a refetch - the query has been made, and now there's no data for it in the cache, so it has to go get the data again.

I recommend using [`queryClient.resetQueries({}, { cancelRefetch: false })`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientresetqueries) instead.  This takes your queries back to their initial state, and `cancelRefresh: false` specifies that any inflight queries will not be refetched.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late reply. I will test your approach and let you know